# Combine multiple raw sound data and save them into one file in actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, flashplayer-10

i built and application that load multiple sound files play it in a sequence as the user
order them but i wonder is there a way to save this sequence into one mp3 or wav file

Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it just with flash. If your stuff is an AIR application, you can combine the sounds using a C++ app or somthing like this via NativeProcess or LocalConnection.
In the case of a web app, the most simple way to save the sounds to a media server (FMS, RED5), and play back the streams at the same time, or you can use FFMPEG to combine the files.

Comment: i can save the file to wav format using php if i get the bytearrays merged correctelly

Comment: Merging is the main problem. You can save that suff in lot of different ways, that shouldn't be a problem. I know, you can do this using FFMPEG, but not with a flash client.